# JavaScript - Problema con la función setInterval( )

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

intento ser breve, estoy creando un minijuego con JS, y estoy haciendo una especie de menú de dificultad, donde en mi función `dificultad()` **dependiendo** del botón donde pulse el usuario, la función devolverá mediante un `return` los valores Fácil = 3000; Difícil = 1000; God = 100;
Luego con esos valores que devuelve la función, mi idea es meterlo como segundo parámetro en la función `setInterval()`, ya sabéis que esta función tiene 2 parámetros, el primero es una función que quieres que se repita, y el segundo parámetro es la velocidad a la que quieres que se repita.
Pues mi idea es esa, que como segundo parámetro tome una función que vaya a devolver un número dependiendo de la opción del usuario elegida.

**El problema**, no me está funcionando, (en realidad creo saber que pasa pero no sé arreglarlo), creo que si por ejemplo la función dificultad devuelve 3000, y pongo esa función en el interval, me está metiendo en bucle o una cosa rara el 3000 y está ejecutando muchísimas veces el `setInterval()`.

El juego básicamente es una tabla, donde el protagonista se mueve por ella, y el malo intenta atraparte, el objetivo es coger un objeto en la tabla y escapar por una salida. El `setInterval()` es para **controlar** la velocidad a la que se mueve el malo simplemente.

Os pongo el código en cuestión a ver si podemos solucionarlo, gracias de antemano.

`timer = setInterval("atrapar()", "dificultad()");`

```
function dificultad() {
//Primero creo las opciones de dificultad que serán botones (fácil dificil god)
var opciones;
for (let i = 0; i<3;i++){
    opciones=document.createElement("input");
    opciones.type="button";
    
    document.body.appendChild(opciones);
}
var arrayOpciones = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']");
//Deshabilito el botón de dificultad para que no pueda volver a ser clickado
arrayOpciones[2].disabled=true;

arrayOpciones[3].value="Fasil";
arrayOpciones[4].value="Dificil"
arrayOpciones[5].value="God";

arrayOpciones[3].addEventListener("click",()=>{
    //alert ("Has dado click en Fasil");
    
    
    return 2000;
})
arrayOpciones[4].addEventListener("click",()=>{
    //alert ("Has dado click en Dificil");
   
    return 10000;

});
arrayOpciones[5].addEventListener("click",()=>{
    //alert ("Has dado click en God");
    
    return 100000000;
});
console.log(arrayOpciones[5].value);
```

}

Aclarar que la función `dificultad()` será llamada cuando el usuario haga click en el botón de Dificultad, lo tengo así planteado en el HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Dificultad" onclick="dificultad()">
```

Los Alert funcionan, y he probado varios console log y consigo sacar el número sin problemas, el fallo está en no saberlo implementar en el `setInterval()`
Por cierto, el segundo parámetro que veis que lo tengo entre comillas dobles `""` era porque estaba probando a ver si era fallo de eso, las comillas no son necesarias.

Un saludo.

Comment: te ahorras codigo pasandole al callback de `addEventListener("click",(e)=>` y luego haciendo  `let self = e.target` el evento retorna especificamente a quien se le dio click entonces si haces `e.target.value` tendras el valor del boton que le diste click ahora solo seria un hace unos `if()` para validar que dificultad...

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar creando variables globales, es un poco chapuzas pero ha colado y va de lujo jaja

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function dificultad() {
// seleccionamos al padre
let buttons = document.querySelector("div");
let dificultades = {"facil": 3000,"dificil" : 1000  , "god" : 100};
buttons.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
  // del evento tomamos el target
  let self = e.target;
  // validamos que sea un elemento typo input
  if( e.target.nodeName == "INPUT"){
     // pasamos el valor a minuscula 
     let val = self.value.toLowerCase();
     // validamos que exista esa llave en nuestro diccionario
     if(dificultades[self.value.toLowerCase()]){
           // pasamos la llave ej. "facil" cuyo valor es 3000
           let puntos =  dificultades[self.value.toLowerCase()];
          // hacemos un alert
           alert(`le diste click a ${val} con valor ${puntos}`);
          // limpiamos el intervalo                                              
          //clearInterval(timer);
          // volvemos a cargar interval
          //timer = setInterval( function, puntos);
        }
  }
});

}

dificultad()
```

```html
<div>
<input type="button" value="facil">
<input type="button" value="intermedio">
<input type="button" value="dificil">
<input type="button" value="god">
</div>
```

Comment: Está genial, lo hice de otra forma al final, pero sirve. Gracias ^^